# Modify date format in R

Tags: r, strptime

So i have a dataframe which has date columns and all the columns can have different formats

```
> DateCol1      DateCol2     DateCol3       DateCol4      DateCol5
> 24-08-2011   2011-12-24     08/1900/24    12/13/2011    Jan 31 1895
```

I know that i can use **strptime/as.Date/as.POSIXct** for each of them individually but since the dataframe will be generated on run time , i won't know the contents beforehand

So how do I convert all of them to the default R format in a generic function/statement ?

Comment: `lubridate` is your friend.   `install.packages("lubridate")`

Comment: Regardless of what package you use, this task sounds like it borders on impossible to do automatically. How would one determine if `01-02-2013` is `1st of February` or `2nd of January` without at least some input from yourself?

Comment: you are right and i guess i might need to come up with some predefined constant formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `guess_formats` from the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
fmts <- lapply(dat, guess_formats, c("m d y", "d-M-y", "Y-m-d",  "m Y d"))
fmts <- lapply(fmts, "[[", 1)
as.data.frame(mapply(parse_date_time, x=dat, orders=fmts))
```

Comment: This can be a possible solution but it still depends on my knowledge of all the possible formats....but i guess as @thelatemail commented , it can be quite daunting without some input

Comment: of course.  You are asking a machine to make a decision without giving it all of the information necessary to make such a decision.  What works about `guess_formats` is that you can give it several options to try and it will return what has worked (and has not).  Play around with it, and add some human knowledge ;)